# How can I segue based on which cell was tapped in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

I have a view controller with a table view embedded inside it, although it is always the same ten cells, I made it dynamic as you cannot make static table view cell inside a UIViewController. My question is, in `prepare(for:)` how can I segue to a view controller based on which cell was tapped? Each cell should navigatie to a completely different VC, but I think having ten segues is a mess.

Is there a better way?

Comment: yes this become more mess but if you want to use segue then you can differentiate them with  segue . identifier

Comment: I prefer not to use this many segues. can I do something in ```didSelectRow(at:)```, maybe based on indexPath user tapped, say which vc?

Comment: *you cannot make static table view cell inside a UIViewController*. Why not?

Comment: I think you can using a container view, but I don't think it would help my issue, not sure.

Comment: Actually it was a rhetorical question. Of course you can embed an UITableView with static cells in a UIViewController.

Comment: Would that be better design than dynamic

Comment: It depends on your concrete design. The question is quite broad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can implement the `UITableViewDelegate` protocol to actually detect the cell being tapped:

```
extension MyOriginViewController {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        // I'm assuming you have only 1 section
        switch indexPath.row {
            case 0:
                // Instantiate the VC
                let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyViewControllerIdentifier")
                // Present the view controller, I'm using a UINavigationController for that
                navigationController?.push(vc, animated: true)
            case 1:
                // Another VC and push or present modally
                let vc = ...
                self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
            default:
                // Default case (unconsidered index)
                print("Do something else")
        }
    }
}
```

So if you have this:
[image: Storyboard]

You can do:

```
let vc = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MyNavController")
self.navigationController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: This works but there is a issue. the screen I am navigating to is presented modally.  If I do push like in case0, it take a full screen, when I do present like in case1 the nav bar is hidden.

Comment: You can `push` on a `UINavigationController` only. If you need to present modally, you use `present`. You present modally on top of what view controller you need to cover. If you present on the navigation controller, the navbar will be hidden.

Comment: so there is no way for a modal view to have a navigation item that can be seen?

Comment: Yes, you would need to instantiate a `UINavigationController` and present that instead of the child view controller. In your storyboard you would set the identifier to the navigation controller and use that.

Comment: here is my code. First I set the ID on the navigation controller in storyboard and then added this: ```navigationController?.present(allergyTableViewController, animated: true, completion: nil) ```

Comment: Is your `allergyTableViewController` behind a navigation controller? So in your storyboard you have an arrow from the navController to the allergy one? Set the identifier to the *navigation controller* and instantiate just like the example above. Remember that `UINavigationController` is a subclass of `UIViewController` and, thus, it can be presented by itself.

Comment: yes. I have a nav controller with a arrow to my allergy